# Developing iphone app Adobe Professional CS5.5 windows version?

Tags: iphone, flash, adobe

Is it possible to develop an iphone app in the windows version of flash professional cs5.5 and publish to an iphone?

Comment: If you haven't started development yet, take a look at the Corona SDK: coronasdk.com. As an Objective-C programmer, I recommend this to all my friends who want to develop for iPhone but don't have the time to learn XCode.

Comment: Wow, I've just had a look at the Corona SDK. It looks excellent! A really intuitive way to build apps. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop in the windows, but build it in the iPhone only in a Mac OS =S
Have fun with Corona SDK =)